# Activity not responding in android Surfaceview

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am trying out a simple game type app where i draw co-ordinates on the screen where the user has clicked.

The problem is , the app gives ANR if i dont click for some time

[My code is listed here](http://pastebin.com/s53Qgdag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a little bit confusing (there is probably a lot of things to clean).

Anyway I think the problem is the following : after a some times of inactivity the `SurfaceViewTest.onPause()` is called by the Android OS. This method call `renderView.pause()` where you have an infinite loop

```
while(true){...}
```

and so the `pause()` method never ends.

If you write :

```
while(renderThread.isAlive()){...}
```

it will solve the issue you are describing.